# Passing value instead of whole object with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm parsing a .json file and am showing all available options in a select:

```
<div bo-switch-when="dropdown">
  <fieldset>
      <select ng-options="options.text for option in question.body.options" ng-model="question.answer" ></select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

It is working, but not as I want it to.  Instead of getting the whole object to my model, I just want to have the value of this object. Via Chrome Dev Tools:

This object (as in the picture) is in my model. **I just want to have the text.**

But when i change my ng-options to this:

```
ng-options="options.text for option.text in question.body.options"
```

it isn't working at all...

[image]

Comment: Tell me... its friday and maybe i am missing something. I have different kind of elements (radio buttons, checkboxes etc.) and my validation works with text, not with whole objects. So i want to change the passing value, not my function in the model.

Comment: @chandu tried to ask you to provide a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/), so that we can help you more easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually a pretty common question among Angular developers.

You can use `ng-repeat`, like so:

```
<select ng-model="question.answer" >
  <option ng-repeat="option in question.body.options" value="{{option.text}}">{{option.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 11):

According to [ngOptions documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) you can specify the property of the object to be used as options value `select as label for (key , value) in object`
 where `select` is the property binded to the model and `label` is the property used as options label.
No need to ngRepeat  here.

In your case just use .text property in both select and label :

> ```
>  <select ng-options="option.text as option.text for option in question.body.options" ng-model="question.answer" >
> ```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that for those looking for setting an id as the value, and displaying something else, she'd use `option.key as option.text for option in question.body.options` instead.